# <div class="nav-collapse collapse"> links not showing up. One Month Rails course

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on the One Month Rails course and have hit a snag.  I am on the video for "Adding Bootstrap" and I am attempting to add a navigation bar to the top of the page.  When I add the code in, the Home & About link disappear.  Please review the code and let me know if anything looks wrong and if there is a chance something else is wrong in one of the other folders...Could it also be the version of Bootrap?

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><%= link_to 'Login', '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Could it also be the version of Bootrap? [sic]" Yes, quite likely. Bootstrap v3 is NOT backward-compatible with Bootstrap v2.

Comment: make sure to always use the versions mentioned in courses. if they don't provide downloads or version information that course sucks!

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  It was the version of Bootstrap.  As mentioned I should use the version that is being shown in the course.